# How to set the Alfresco drop down list to show a default value?

Tags: alfresco, freemarker, alfresco-share

I am using Alfresco selectone.ftl to customize a dropdown list. I do not want to show any blank option as default. But the Selectone.ftl automatically adds a blank option. How to set `my value` as the default and delete the blank option.

Answer (score 0):

There is Requirement where i have to display list of user in dropdown base on some condition , for that i have customize selectone.ftl as per below code,may be helpful to you.

**   This is custom-selectone.ftl**

```
<div class="form-field">
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
YAHOO.util.Event.onAvailable("${fieldHtmlId}", function(){
    new selectAjax("${fieldHtmlId}");
});
function selectAjax(currentValueHtmlId) {
    this.currentValueHtmlId = currentValueHtmlId;
    var select = Dom.get(this.currentValueHtmlId);
    this.register = function () {
        Alfresco.util.Ajax.jsonGet({
            url: Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI+"userwebsacript",
            successCallback: {
                fn: this.updateOptions,
                scope: this
            },
            failureCallback: {
                fn: function(){},
                scope: this
            }
        });
    };
    this.updateOptions = function (res) {

        var result = res.serverResponse.responseText;
        if (result.length > 0) {
            var sp=result.split(",");
            for(var i=0;i<sp.length;i++){
                var option = new Option(sp[i], sp[i]);
                select.options[select.options.length] = option;
            }  
        }
    };

    this.register();
}
//]]></script>
<label for="${fieldHtmlId}">${field.label?html}:<#if field.mandatory><span class="mandatory-indicator">${msg("form.required.fields.marker")}</span></#if></label>
<select id="${fieldHtmlId}" name="${field.name}" tabindex="0"
        <#if field.description??>title="${field.description}"</#if>
        <#if field.control.params.size??>size="${field.control.params.size}"</#if>
        <#if field.control.params.styleClass??>class="${field.control.params.styleClass}"</#if>
        <#if field.control.params.style??>style="${field.control.params.style}"</#if>
        <#if field.disabled  && !(field.control.params.forceEditable?? && field.control.params.forceEditable == "true")>disabled="true"</#if>>
        <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```